# Let $K$ be a number field. Does it exist an extension $K \subseteq L$ of finite degree such that $\mathcal{O}_L$ is a PID?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

By the finiteness of ideal class group follows that for every number field $K$ it exists an extension $K \subseteq L$ of finite degree such that every ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$ becomes principal in $\mathcal{O}_L$.

I was wondering if the following generalization is true: for every number field $K$ it exists an extension $K \subseteq L$ of finite degree such that $\mathcal{O}_L$ is a PID.

I suspect it is not true, but I have no intuition about it and I do not know anything serious about Algebraic Number Theory. It is just a curiosity.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_number_fields_with_class_number_one, there is no proven *positive* answer. Actually, the answer seems negative: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92237/embedding-number-fields-in-fields-with-class-number-1 (there are Hilbert towers involved).